# Line chart period maxPeriod

Tags: amcharts

I have a dataset that has datetime and I want to shown my data with a period. But if my data set has anordinary data without period also it must be shown.

My dataset;
18.10.2017 08:00
18.10.2017 08:15
18.10.2017 08:30
**18.10.2017 08:40**
18.10.2017 09:15

My period: 15 min

How I can see data on 18.10.2017 08:40?

Mydata:

```
    [
        {
        "column-1": 8,
        "column-2": 5,
        "date": "2014-03-01 08:00"
        },
        {
        "column-1": 6,
        "column-2": 7,
        "date": "2014-03-01 08:15"
        },
        {
        "column-1": 1,
        "column-2": 3,
        "date": "2014-03-01 08:30"
        },
        {
        "column-1": 5,
        "column-2": 3,
        "date": "2014-03-01 08:40"
        },
        {
        "column-1": 2,
        "column-2": 1,
        "date": "2014-03-01 09:15"
        },
        {
        "column-1": 3,
        "column-2": 2,
        "date": "2014-03-01 09:30"
        },
        {
        "column-1": 6,
        "column-2": 8,
        "date": "2014-03-01 09:45"
        }
```

[image: ]]

Comment: You should explain better what you want.

Comment: You should also post code that shows what you have done so far and what the issue is. AmCharts has no problem showing your dataset.

Comment: FYI - when asked to post code, post your full code (in this case, the chart config is also helpful). See my response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your [`minPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#minPeriod) is set to the lowest period that can display your data. If your data isn't always in 15 minute increments, then use `"mm"` instead of `"15mm"`. Since you have gaps, you'll also want to set the [`gapPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#gapPeriod) to a value that best represents where you want the gap to appear - if your data is usually within 15 minutes, then set it to 15.1:

```
  graphs: [
    {
      // ...
      connect: false,
      gapPeriod: 15.1,
      // ...
    },{
      // ...
      connect: false,
      gapPeriod: 15.1,
      // ...
    }
  ],
  // ...
  categoryAxis: {
    parseDates: true,
    minPeriod: "mm"
  }
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/5854dd85de31799d8e73b4faa33f418d?editors=0010)

Comment: Not necessarily *all* your code, just enough to reproduce your screenshot - data and makeChart config in this case is enough. A jsfiddle is also helpful. Help us help you. :) See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details.